# Implementing Google Adsense inside a p(react) project using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, adsense

I have an issue and I've spent A LOT OF TIME trying to solve this. I am trying to add the Google Adsense code to my Preact project which works the same as React. My status stays stuck at: "**Your site needs work**". the additional information explains that Google can't find the code. Even though I've added it (in multiple ways).

What I've found out is that every time this line:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-#####" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

gets transformed to this line:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-#####" async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-checked-head="true"></script>
```

This is how I'm trying to add the code:

**Option 1: In my app.js file**

```
componentDidMount() {
        //SetAdsense
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('data-ad-client','ca-pub-########' );
        script.setAttribute('async');
        script.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";           
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

**Option 2: Using Helmet**

```
<Helmet>
   <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-#####" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

Any idea how I can make Google see the provided Adsense code in my Head?

***UPDATE 1 23/07/2020***
I've just found out that the reason for not getting Adsense implemented is not related to the way I've implemented the Adsense code snippet. 2 reasons for this assumption:

```
Adsense has unapproved my website with the message: No content provided (which is strange because I've tested the crawlresults in the Google Webmaster tools and it crawls my website like a charm).
This solution has the same changes in the snippet and the Ads are still working.
https://react-adsense.xmplaylist.com/
```

So my issues could be related to Preact (or the usage of any JS framework). I cant figure out why exatly yet, because I prerender al my pages (using the json file) and running the `preact build` should automatically use that json to prerender all these pages right?

My prerender-urls.json looks like this:

```
[{  
    "url": "/",
    "title": "Homepage"
  },
  {  
    "url": "/error",
    "title": "ErrorPage"
  },
  {  
    "url": "/other",
    "title": "Other"
  }
 etc.etc.etc.
```

**UPDATE 2 24/7/2020**

If I open a random page>index.html it looks like this  (see screenshot) in Chrome. I'm shure thats why Google Adsense request gets disaproved.How can I prerender the pages WITH the content rendered as well? All static content is visible in the screenshot.All dynamic content comes from a JSON file which gets loaded by javascript. I use the URL as the key to determine which content should be displayed.
[image]

Kind regards!

Comment: Your code looks correct. `data-checked-head` is added by adsbygoogle.js upon initialization so it is expected that you see it when inspecting DOM in devtools. Do you see `/pagead/ads` request in network tab in devtools?

Comment: Hey thanks! Yes I do see pagead.googlesyndication etc. But this is after I've implemented in hardcoded in the index.html of the build. Damn dirty solution I know ;)

Comment: Do you know what was adding `data-checked-head="true"` in your react solution? As I understand it was added by something (react?) before the tag was added to browser DOM? Wondering if we need to change approach to not use `data-checked-head` attribute if these kind of pre-processing are common and they break adsbygoogle.js.

Comment: It has something to do with the Preact CLI rendering. Please see my update above. @MikitaBelahlazau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by moving the function that sets the content to the componentWillRender(). So the issue I was facing was lifecycle related.